# curl php a http que redirecciona a un https

Tags: http, curl

Tengo un problema, trato de hacer curl a una url que contiene un post a una url https, el problema es que solo me captura la primera url y se salta a la segunda pero esta no la captura.
url 1 : `http: //s7494.home. us/m/fun4.php`
url 2 : `https: www.url.com`

este es el codigo de mi curl

link: `http: //s7494.home. us/m/ m/in4d.php`

```
<?php 
    $url = "http: //s7494.home. us/m/fun1.php"; //Let me say for example take paypal.com and try 
    $connection = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLPROTO_HTTPS, 1);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)'); 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec($connection); 
    curl_close($connection); 
    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que curl siga la redirección con la opción CURLOP_FOLLOWLOCATION en teoría lo tendrías resuelto, pero creo que no es el problema, ya que no hay redirección ninguna. Puedes comprobar la respuesta de la conexión con:

```
echo curl_getinfo($connection, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

La url http://s7494.home.us/m/fun4.php tiene este etiquetado:

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('form').submit()">
```

Cuando haces el echo se dispara el evento onload y hace el submit del formulario, pero en ningún caso es una redirección.

Comment: gracias por responder, utilizando curl logré hacer post directamente a la web que necesito sin necesidad de usar el form en fun1.php. ahora tengo otro problema, las cookies de sección, resulta que si ejecuto fun1.php el post se hace correctamente, pero si lo hago desde curl no.

Comment: he probado haciendo post desde fun1.php, descargo el valor de la cookie y lo ingreso a curl  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'BIGipServerTomcat_Simit_Pool=3332641452.62751.0000; JSESSIONID=1AE60EE8CF224A75C1DE67C821B36271');

Comment: veo que en cada vez lo unico que cambia es el valor de JSESSIONID=1AE60EE8CF224A75C1DE67C821B36271 y funciona por unos minutos, luego supongo que expira esta cookie y nuevamente me genera un error de sección. puedes ayudarme? hay alguna forma de capturar esta cookie cada vez que se ejecute curl? porque de otra forma no tendria sentido estar cambiandola desde el codigo. gracias

Comment: ya lo solucione, muchas gracias